# Python Pandas - Reformat Datetime Index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two data frames that are both multi-indexed on 'Date' and 'name', and want to do a SQL style `JOIN` to combine them. I've tried

```
pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['name', 'Date'], how='inner')
```

which then results in an empty DataFrame.

If I inspect the data frames I can see that the index of one is represented as `'2015-01-01'` and the other is represented as `'2015-01-01 00:00:00'` which explains my issues with joining.

Is there a way to 'recast' the index to a specific format within pandas?

I've included the tables to see what data I'm working with.

```
df1=
+-------------+------+------+------+
|    Date     | name | col1 | col2 |
+-------------+------+------+------+
| 2015-01-01  | mary |   12 |  123 |
| 2015-01-02  | mary |   23 |   33 |
| 2015-01-03  | mary |   34 |   45 |
| 2015-01-01  | john |   65 |   76 |
| 2015-01-02  | john |   67 |   78 |
| 2015-01-03  | john |   25 |   86 |
+-------------+------+------+------+

df2= 
+------------+------+-------+-------+
|    Date    | name | col3  | col4  |
+------------+------+-------+-------+
| 2015-01-01 | mary | 80809 | 09885 |
| 2015-01-02 | mary | 53879 | 58972 |
| 2015-01-03 | mary | 23887 |  3908 |
| 2015-01-01 | john |  9238 |  2348 |
| 2015-01-02 | john |   234 |   234 |
| 2015-01-03 | john |  5325 |  6436 |
+------------+------+-------+-------+
```

DESIRED Result:

```
+-------------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|    Date     | name | col1 | col2  | col3  | col4  |
+-------------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2015-01-01  | mary |   12 |   123 | 80809 | 09885 |
| 2015-01-02  | mary |   23 |    33 | 53879 | 58972 |
| 2015-01-03  | mary |   34 |    45 | 23887 |  3908 |
| 2015-01-01  | john |   65 |    76 |  9238 |  2348 |
| 2015-01-02  | john |   67 |    78 |   234 |   234 |
| 2015-01-03  | john |   25 |    86 |  5325 |  6436 |
+-------------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Sorry are your 'Date' dtypes datetimes?

Comment: It's multi - indexed, but when I print a concatenated table it shows some dates as `'2015-06-09 00:00:00'` and `u'2013-04-17'` so I think some are strings and others are datetimes. Can I convert them? I tried `df.index = df.index.date` but I'm having difficulty access the single component of the multi index.

Comment: After resetting the index, convert the dtype using `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` you should then be able to merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cannot join is because you have different dtypes on the indicies. Pandas silently fails if the indicies have different dtypes.

You can easily change your indicies from string representations of time to proper pandas datetimes like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":range(1,30)}, index=['2015-04-{}'.format(d) for d in range(1,30)])

df.index.dtype
dtype('O')

df.index = df.index.to_series().apply(pd.to_datetime)

df.index.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Now you can merge the dataframes on their index:

```
pd.merge(left=df, left_index=True,
         right=df2, right_index=True)
```

Assuming you have a df2, which my example is omitting...